# Split/Sort nested list into a dictionary based on values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested list which I would like to split and sort into the dictionary, based on a specific value inside a nested list.

Here is an example code:

```
list = [['item1',['some_value1', 1]], [['item2',['some_value2', 2]], ['item3',['some_value3', 1]]]

# I would like to convert this list into a dictionary

final_dict1 = {1:{'item1':['some_value1', 1], 'item3':['some_value3', 1]}, 2:{'item2':['some_value2', 2]}}

# OR

final_dict2 = {1:[['item1',['some_value1', 1]], ['item3',['some_value3', 1]]], 2:['item2':['some_value2', 2]]}
```

Basically I want to sort list items based on specific key inside their respective sublist, and make a dictionary out of it.

Comment: Where is your coding attempt?  You identified the two steps you need, each of which is covered well by on-line tutorials.

Comment: @Prune I have tried searching for tutorial/article online, but couldn't find anything that would help me with the task. If you know of any article that can help me out, I would be very grateful.

Comment: How many levels does the nesting goes?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Just 2 nested levels. The list structure is exactly the same as in the example. I just made it shorter for simplicity's sake.

Comment: You search for "Python list sort tutorial" and "Python dict create tutorial".  A slightly more advanced term is "dict comprehension" -- there are also list comprehensions, but I doubt you'll want to use them here.  Asking for a specific off-site link is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: But you have several nested levels in your example. As a matter of fact if you copy directly is not valid Python

Comment: @DanielMesejo Yes, as I mentioned, there are 2 nested levels (3 levels altogether) for the list. Could you please elaborate on the "not valid Python" part? If my example is incorrect, I will fix the code.

Comment: Yes it is incorrect, has a syntax error

Comment: @DanielMesejo I just tested it, and if you simply copy the dictionary that I wrote, without any code before it, there will be no syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do the following (using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)):

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [['item1',['some_value1', 1]], ['item2',['some_value2', 2]], ['item3',['some_value3', 1]]]

result = defaultdict(dict)
for i, (val, idx) in lst:
    result[idx][i] = [val, idx]

print(dict(result))
```

**Output**

```
{1: {'item1': ['some_value1', 1], 'item3': ['some_value3', 1]}, 2: {'item2': ['some_value2', 2]}}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much for the help, I will check the link for more info!

Comment: @TimesAndPlaces Glad I could help, the link provides information on defaultdict.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [['item1',[someValue1, 1]], ['item2',[someValue2, 2]], ['item3',[someValue3, 1]]]

result = {}
for i, item in enumerate(list):
    result[i] = {item[1][0]: item[1][1]}
```

Comment: Hmm, it returns an error message ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'```

Comment: I fixed it, sorry for that. Please try again

Comment: Alright, it did run the code, however, the result is not exactly what I am looking for: ```{0: {'some_value1': 1}, 1: {'item3': ['some_value3', 1]}}``` It seems like it "swallowed" second item in the list.